# Can not load rgl package

Tags: rstudio, rgl

I´m trying to load the package NormqPCR in RStudio (Version 1.1.463) and macOS Mojave Version 10.14.3. When I try to load the package with library("NormqPCR") Y get the following output:

```
> library("NormqPCR", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library")
Loading required package: RColorBrewer
Loading required package: qpcR
Loading required package: MASS
Loading required package: minpack.lm
Loading required package: rgl
|
```

After that, RStudio don´t respond and I have to force quit RStudio.
Then I load all this packages one by one, and when I try with rgl, RStudio don´t responde again, so, I guess that the problem is this package. 
Anyone can help me with this trouble? Because I still haven´t been able to fix it!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I can solve this trouble! I just install XQuartz on my computer and then I can be able to load rgl package and NormqPCR